# Adjust length of y-axis using chart.js and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

I have my chart canvas in the following structure:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- something -->
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <!-- something -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
        <canvas class="chart chart-bubble" chart-data="c.data" chart-options="c.options" chart-series="c.series"></canvas>    
    </div>

</div>
```

Using this, I have my Chart on the right side, and next to it on the left side are two other rows. I want it to look like this:

[image]

But for some reason, the height is not fully used by the chart.
It looks like this:

[image]

I can't just set another height for the canvas, because then, the chart becomes distorted.
How can I make the y-axis longer, so the height of the chart becomes bigger and the full height of the layout is used?

Comment: This [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html)  and this [example](https://codepen.io/chartjs/pen/YVWZbz) may help you

Comment: using an outer container, I can adjust width but not height for some reason. The ratio is fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set this attribute of the options-object for the chart:

```
maintainAspectRatio: false
```

Then I could adjust the height like:

```
.chart-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 65vh;
}
```